# OPTIONS return 204, POST return 200 but data is not entered in db

Tags: json, rest, extjs

I am using jsonplaceholder (http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) locally. I am testing my GET and POST calls via extjs rest proxy. 
I am able to read data. But when I create a model object and save it, the HTTp code for option is 204 and for POST is 200
BUT data is not stored in database of jsonplaceholder local server.
Any Idea where actual problem exists?

Comment: Isn't that expected behavior?

Comment: @lorenz you are right. App is working fine :) There was a small issue but it is not related to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with [json-server](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) and this is the expected results and for your knowledge, here is a detailed explanation of HTTP Status codes [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).